# Select everything after a common deliminator in Presto

Tags: presto

I have a column where i want to take just the numbers.

However, the data is stored like this:

[image: so the colon would be a common deliminator, but this has a different number of colons so I can't just split the string.]
I want to have just the numbers to be outputted in the same column. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`regexp_extract`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract) function. Assuming your values are always numbers, this should do it:

```sql
SELECT regexp_extract(value, '.*:(\d+)', 1) 
FROM data
```